# How to have Office 2013+ Applications Open to Blank (Workbook, Document, etc) automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013

Every time I launch microsoft excel 2013 (2016) (or Word, etc) it gives me a screen where I need to select which template I want to open -

[image]

How do I avoid this selection screen, like in other versions of Office?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the **Start Screen**. To disable it, select your blank workbook (or whatever template you want) and go to

File - Options - General  and uncheck the "*Show the Startscreen when this application starts*":

[image]