# Always open 'Blank Workbook' when clicking (File) > (New), and when Excel first opens

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, templates

I use a lot of temporary workbooks, and when I open existing workbooks, I do it from my desktop or elsewhere.  I **don't *ever*** want to see Excel's list of `Featured` or `Personal` templates that I have-never used and will-never use, and I **definitely do *not*** want to `Search online for more`.

I would like Excel to **automatically open a `Blank Workbook` *any time*** that I:

- ***open* Excel**, or,
- ***click* <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>New</kbd>**.

[image: screenshot]

I am aware that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> but honestly, I never, ever remember, and that only solves half the problem anyhow.

I'm surprised I've never seen a setting for this, but I'm thinking there must be a **registry key** or other buried settings?

And if not, can I at least delete or at least **hide *all*** the templates (that I've never even *seen* anyone use)...?  (The only context commands on right-click are `Preview`, `Create`, and `Pin`.)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to keep the start window with Blank Workbook template or just want to open Excel without Start Window? How about other Office applications?

Comment: @Lee The answer below did what I needed.  The only other Office app I use frequently is Access, which doesn't have the same option, but that's not a big deal since I'm not creating dozens of new DB's per day (like I am with workbooks).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have Office 2013 Applications Open to Blank (Workbook, Document, etc) automatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/836134/how-to-have-office-2013-applications-open-to-blank-workbook-document-etc-aut)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Disable the Start Screen

Here's how to disable the Start screen so that you go directly to a blank workbook when opening Excel:

1. Open the program and, click **File** > **Options**.
2. Under *Start up options*, uncheck the **Show the Start screen when this application starts** box and close the program.

   [image]

   [Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-the-start-screen-1f2834b4-09d4-490d-9c04-5d9f1b25ff70)

### Remove Featured Templates

I doubt there's a way to avoid the new design for the **New workbook** screen. It's an integral part of the application's interface. The CTRL+N shortcut may be your best bet for bypassing it.

However, according to [this site](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2016&Policy=office16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_DisablehyperlinkstowebtemplatesinFileNewandtaskpanes) you can disable the Featured Templates section with the following Registry value:

```
Registry Hive    HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Registry Path    software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\common\general
Value Name       disablehyperlinkstowebtemplates
Value Type       REG_DWORD
Enabled Value    1
Disabled Value   0
```

---

`disablehyperlinkstowebtemplates=0` *`(default)`*      `disablehyperlinkstowebtemplates=1`

[image: disablehyperlinkstowebtemplates=0] [image: disablehyperlinkstowebtemplates=1]

Comment: Disabling the Start Screen (in Options) solved 80% of the annoyance (*Figures* that I've been through those options a million times and never noticed that one!).  For the other one, I only had as far as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0` so I added the last 2 keys & the value.  It disables the `Search for online templates` bar and strangely hides *some* of the templates & *changes the formatting* on the remaining ones, but that's close enough.  (I'll add screenshots to the end of your answer.)  Appreciate the help; thanks!